# Get the values of 4 unknowns from 2 given equations

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, sympy

I have 2 equations in which there are a total of 10 values and out of these 10 values 6 are known and the rest 4 values are unknown. Is there any method in python which could solve this type of problem?[image]

I am talking about the second and fourth equations. Here all the X values are known and in the fourth equation, it is μ12 instead of μ21.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy can tell you what two of the 4 are in terms of the other two (and known values):

```
>>> from sympy import var, solve
var('i1 x2d k12 x1 x3 mu12 x2 x4 i2 x4d mu21')
(i1, x2d, k12, x1, x3, mu12, x2, x4, i2, x4d, mu21)
>>> solve(
... (i1*x2d-(k12*(x1-x3)+mu12*(x2-x4)),
... i2*x4d-(k12*(x3-x1)+mu21*(x4-x2))),
...    (i1,i2,mu12,mu21))
{i1: mu12*(x2 - x4)/x2d + (k12*x1 - k12*x3)/x2d,
 i2: mu21*(-x2 + x4)/x4d + (-k12*x1 + k12*x3)/x4d}
```